# Showing a function of random walk is a martingale

Tags: probability, martingales

I would like a hint for the following problem:

> Consider a biased random walk on the integers with probability $p<1/2$ of moving to the right and probability $1-p$ of moving to the left.  Let $S_n$ be the value at time $n$ and assume that $S_0=a$, where $0<a<N$. Show that $M_n=[(1-p)/p]^{S_{n}}$ is a martingale.

I need to show that $\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|S_{0}, \dots S_{n}] = M_{n}$. However
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|S_{0}, \dots, S_{n}] &= \mathbb{E}[[(1-p)/p]^{S_{n+1}}|S_{0}, \dots, S_{n}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[[(1-p)/p]^{S_{n+1}}|S_{n}] &&\text{(By Markovity.)} \\
&= [(1-p)/p]^{p(S_{n}+1) + (1-p)(S_{n}-1)} \\
&= [(1-p)/p]^{S_{n}+2p-1},
\end{align}
$$
which is not what I need. So it seems that either I'm making a mistake or the problem is wrong.

**Am I making a mistake?**

**Is $M_n$ a martingale?**

Comment: I don't think $E[M_{n+1}]=((1-p)/p)^{E[{S_{n+1}}]}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is that $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbf{E}} \E(\exp(S_{n+1}))$ is not the same as $\exp(\E(S_{n+1}))$. Here's the corrected work: 
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[M_{n+1} \mid S_0, \ldots, S_n] 

&= \mathbf{E} \left[ \left.  \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^{S_{n+1}} \right| \ S_0, \ldots, S_n \right] 

\\ &= p \cdot \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^{S_n + 1}  +  (1-p) \cdot \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^{S_n - 1}  

\\ &= p \cdot \frac{1-p}{p} \cdot M_n  +  (1-p) \cdot \left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{-1}  \cdot  M_n

\\ &= (p + (1-p)) \cdot M_n 

\\ &= M_n.

\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I think $(1-p)\cdot \frac{1-p}{p}$ should be $(1-p)\cdot \frac{p}{1-p}$.

Comment: @Srivatsan I took the liberty and added a missing power. Feel free to roll back if it was not a typo.

Comment: Thanks, @Sasha. That was indeed a typo.